# disable/not render an imported stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css

how to `disable/not render` an **imported** (imported with `@import` rule) css stylesheet **without modifying** the css file ?

Some stylesheet imports it with a rule:

```
@import"stylesheets/jquery-ui.css";
```

I have tried this:

```
var el=document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
        if(el[i].src == "stylesheets/jquery-ui.css") {
            el[i].disabled="disabled";
        }
    }
```

But this wouldn't work for a reason that it is not a part of DOM, so question is how would I get it done then?

Comment: Hang on a minute! An imported css file has the following markup: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename.css">` - Noticed the problem yet? The path to the file is held in the `href` attribute of the element, not the `src` attribute (which doesn't exist here). Once fixed, your code should be just fine. ;)

Comment: thanks, hadn't noticed it :D, but anyway this **won't stop** it from rendering, as the stylesheet imported with the `@import` rule **doesn't become** a part of DOM

Comment: Is there some sort of CSS preprocessor involved? In that case, the preprocessor is likely handling the `@import` and you won't even see it in the DOM. You'll have to kill it in some other way, such as by replacing `stylesheets/jquery-ui.css` with an empty file.

Comment: @Random - Are you certain about that? As it stands, I'd consider your question to be incomplete - it really should include the generated html, such that answers may be given, rather than guessed at.

Comment: @torazaburo yes, `SASS` is involved, and @enhzflep @torazaburo is right     with the above mentioned fact about `CSS preprocessors`,but `jquery-ui.css` is being used on other pages, so it won't be suitable to replace/change it